# Debug ASP NET Core 2 in Docker in Visual Studio 2017 error

Tags: docker, visual-studio-2017, asp.net-core-2.0

I have a simpe ASP NET Core 2 app and tried to debug it using Docker. But when I hit F5 I get this error dialog box:

```
---------------------------
Microsoft Visual Studio
---------------------------
Debugging Error

The launch URL 'http://{ServiceHost}' is invalid.
---------------------------
OK   
---------------------------
```

The app is running and I can just launch my browser manually to view it, but the dialog box and the lack of automation is kind of annoying. Is there anything I can do to get rid of this?

Comment: There's a lot of issues with container debugging in general with dotnet core 2.0 and VS2017. There's an ongoing bug where the debugger will just timeout, and royally hose visual studio. 2019 is getting ready to go into preview, so I'm hoping it sucks less

Answer (score 0):

For launching project from docker in VS 2017. There are two options which is set asp.net core project as Startup project, and choose `Docker` to debug, another is adding `docker-compose project`, and launch from `docker-compose project`.

If you mean first one, you could follow steps below to change `launch url`.

```
Asp.Net Core project->Properties->launchSettings.json->change `launchUrl` in docker node with your valide value.
```

If you mean second one, it will launch the web browser by the `Service URL` in docker-compose Property Pages. You could check `Service URL` by right click `docker-compose project` and click `Properties`.

**Option1**:

Changes the `Service URL` with your expected value.

**Options2**:

Define your like below which specifying the prots

```
version: '3.4'

services:
webapplication2:
environment:
  - ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development
  - ASPNETCORE_URLS=https://+:443;http://+:80
  - ASPNETCORE_HTTPS_PORT=44366
ports:
  - "56355:80"
  - "44366:443"
volumes:
  - ${APPDATA}/ASP.NET/Https:/root/.aspnet/https:ro
  - ${APPDATA}/Microsoft/UserSecrets:/root/.microsoft/usersecrets:ro
```